# Domain email forwarding for group discussions

Tags: domains, email

I am using *Hostinger* for my website and domain.

With my previous webhost, I was able to send a mail to one account, for example `group1@mydomain.example`, and it would then automatically be forwarded to multiple email adresses that I had entered in the webhost mailing dashboard. Everyone would then be able to see each others replies to that email. It was very useful for discussions between the people in the mailing list.

I can't seem to find a way to do this directly from the *Hostinger* dashboard. Does anyone know a way I could do this via *Hostinger* or otherwise via some workaround?

Comment: If they don't provide mailman or some similar mailing list solution consider moving to another host.